# Finding the dimension of a nested list in python

Tags: python, algorithm, matrix, multidimensional-array

We can create multi-dimensional arrays in python by using nested list, such as:

```
A = [[1,2,3],
     [2,1,3]]
```

etc.
In this case, it is simple nRows= len(A) and nCols=len(A[0]). However, when I have more than three dimensions it would become complicated.

```
A = [[[1,1,[1,2,3,4]],2,[3,[2,[3,4]]]],
     [2,1,3]]
```

etc.
These lists are legal in Python. And the number of dimensions is not a priori.
In this case, how to determine the number of dimensions and the number of elements in each dimension.

I'm looking for an algorithm and if possible implementation. I believe it has something similar to DFS. Any suggestions?

P.S.: I'm not looking for any existing packages, though I would like to know about them.

Comment: Your second example is *inconsistently* multi-dimensional. Consider using `numpy` for this sort of thing, where you can just ask for an object's `shape`.

Comment: What you want is more of a tree than an array (it is not even a jagged array). For it to be an array, you should have a list of lists of values, and not a list of  values OR _other_ lists. The very definition of tree is a structure where every node has a collection where each item is a leaf or another node, thus being recursive.

Comment: I know that the example given is inconsistently  multi-dimensional. Consider a case, if we want to check a given data is a proper array (if you need a practical example) However, as I had mentioned later, the objective is find the algorithm. I'm aware of numpy.py but I'm looking for the algorithm.

Comment: @heltonbiker: I agree with you. It is more like a tree than an array. We could construct a tree in this case and probably determine the dimensions, as values in each node. But that would be slow. I'm looking for an efficient algorithm... Not using packages like numpy or SciPy.

Comment: If you apply the algorithm to this example you posted, what would be the result, and why?

Comment: @ heltonbiker: If the array is consistent/proper matrix, then I expect the algorithm to output the number of elements in each dimension. It will act similar to the size() function in MATLAB. In case of an irregular array, like the one in the example, the algorithm is output an error...

Answer (score 0):

I believe to have solve the problem my self.
It is just a simple DFS.

For the example given above: A = [[[1,1,[1,2,3,4]],2,[3,[2,[3,4]]]],
     [2,1,3]]
the answer is as follows:
[[3, 2, 2, 2, 3, 4], [3]]
The total number of dimensions is the 7.

I guess I was overthinking... thanks anyway...!